# hibernate CriteriaQuery multi select and spring data Specification

Tags: hibernate, spring-data, criteriaquery

mysql is `select e,h from Equipment e,EquipmentHistory h where e.id = h.equipmentId and h.id in (select h2.id from EquipmentHistory h2 where criteria`

how convert to hibernate CriteriaQuery multi select and spring data Specification ?